# Python - coding style - change several variables across functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, global-variables

Problem: One function is reading a configuration file and setting up a lot of variables accordenly.
Several other functions needs several of these variables to do there job.

Best practice says, Global variables are a no-go, so I was thinking what altertives there is to change/use variables that are not local to a function
and when there are a lot of variables to handle ?

The first one is the obvious variable transfer to the function and returning the result as normal.

Second method is to change/use the variables directly, but is this an acceptable python-way to do it, or just an other "way" of the Global variables ?

Third method is to put all variables in transfer, inside a list and use that list in the function...

Which method is the right one to use in Python3 (if one is better than the others) and which one should be avoided (if any)?

And yes, I'm sure that there are several more ways to do it, I just don't know of them at the moment :-)

e.g. #1)

```
def do_something(a, b, c, d, e):
    print(a, b, c, d, e)
    a = 'new1'
    b = 'new2'
    c = 'new3'
    d = 'new4'
    e = 'new5'
    return (a, b, c, d, e)

def main():
    var1 = 'test1'
    var2 = 'test2'
    var3 = 'test3'
    var4 = 'test4'
    var5 = 'test5'
    print(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)
    var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 = do_something(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)
    print(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**e.g. #2)**

```
def do_something():
    print(main.var1, main.var2, main.var3, main.var4, main.var5)
    main.var1 = 'new1'
    main.var2 = 'new2'
    main.var3 = 'new3'
    main.var4 = 'new4'
    main.var5 = 'new5'

def main():
    main.var1 = 'test1'
    main.var2 = 'test2'
    main.var3 = 'test3'
    main.var4 = 'test4'
    main.var5 = 'test5'
    print(main.var1, main.var2, main.var3, main.var4, main.var5)
    do_something()
    print(main.var1, main.var2, main.var3, main.var4, main.var5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**e.g. #3)**

```
def do_something_list(li):
    print(li)
    li[0] = 'new1'
    li[1] = 'new2'
    li[2] = 'new3'
    li[3] = 'new4'
    li[4] = 'new5'
    return (li)

def main():
    var1 = 'test1'
    var2 = 'test2'
    var3 = 'test3'
    var4 = 'test4'
    var5 = 'test5'
    list1 = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]
    print(list1)
    list1 = do_something_list(list1)
    print(list1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: #2 basically abuses the fact that you can assign attributes to a function to avoid defining a class to wrap the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there is no generic solution. Every problem requires an individual approach based on the balance of pros & cons for that specific use-case. What is your use-case?

---

The best way and the most common approach is to use a container object, e.g. "config", and to pass it to every function needed. YOu can then access these variables as `config.myfield` (if it supports field access), or `config['myfield']`, or in the similar ways.

However, this is also not the best solution. But a relatively simple one. Especially when you need to pass the values (e.g. configs) from the top-level (e.g. CLI parser, config parser) to the very low level functions (e.g., the web request processing).

Sometimes, in the bigger frameworks, this config/container object is attached to a per-call entity (e.g., a web `request` in the web frameworks); or made available as a global object (e.g., `request.config` in pytest); or something similar.

In that case, the frameworks take care of delivering the container object into your functions one way or another. They can also ensure that such objects a thread-safe by keeping them in the per-thread memory. And that the objects are immutable (i.e., if one request modifies it, all parallel or further requests will not see the changes).

---

Specifically on you examples, they are all bad (sorry to say that).

Example #1 modifies the function-local variables, which will no be visible in all other functions; if you declare them `global`, they will be module-scoped.

Example #2 assigns the fields to the function object (sic!). And you will have to pass the main function as a config object (bad idea).

Example #3 will work, but is inconvenient: you have to remember which position each of the values have; turning that into a `dict` or a config object with arbitrary fields will do the things, as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about using global variables is not the best way to do something like this. In general the best practice is what you did in example 1. HOWEVER in python there are a couple of things you need to look out for when changing variables inside of a function you passed said var to.

```
def func1(list1, string1):
    list1.append('in func1')
    string1 = 'in func1 string'


def main():
    list1 = ['in main']
    string1 = 'main string'
    func1(list1, string1)
    print list1
    print string1
```

output:

```
['in main', 'in func1']
main string
```

Depending on what type of variable is passed to the function and what you do with it you can unintentionally change it's value in the parent function.

The rule of thumb is if the type of the var passed is an [immutable type](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/) (int, float, decimal, complex, bool ,string ,tuple, range, frozenset, bytes) there is no way to change the initial vars value other than returning a new variable with a new value. In this case best practice is to use a different variable name inside of the child function if you are returning a different value.

If the variable is a [mutable type](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/) (list, dict, set, bytearray, user-defined classes (unless specifically made immutable)) the best practice is to NOT change the variable value in the child function, but to copy the value and return the new variable with the changed value.

```
from copy import deepcopy

def func1(list1):
    new_list = deepcopy(list1)
    new_list.append('in func1')
    return new_list


def main():
    list1 = ['in main']
    new_func_list = func1(list1)
    print list1
    print new_func_list
```

Output:

```
['in main']
['in main', 'in func1']
```

Now there is one more big pitfall you can run into when changing mutable objects in a child function.

```
def func1(list1):
    new_list = list1
    new_list.append('in func1')


def main():
    list1 = ['in main']
    func1(list1)
    print list1
```

Output:

```
['in main', 'in func1']
```

Even when you reassign a mutable variable to a new one the new var is still pointing (meaning you will be editing) the same value as the original variable.